# "you wouldn't know it to see it" vs "you wouldn't recognize it to see it"

Tags: expressions, formality, speech

Is it more correct to say, "you wouldn't know it to see it" or "you wouldn't recognize it to see"? I have tried looking both up on google, and only the first return's actual usage. Also, the formulation of "you wouldn't know it" + "to see it". Is there something special about this construction, it seems odd. I feel that it works in the first example but wouldn't work if I were to apply it formulaically, for example, "You wouldn't eat it to taste it". However, I might be wrong about that.

Comment: Your phrases aren't AmE that I recognize.  What I'm familiar with is "you wouldn't know it if you saw it."

Comment: @Xanne or 'You wouldn't know it til you see it'

Comment: @marcellothearcane You're right, that sounds more like it.

Comment: I think 'know' refers to some quality of 'it' that you would not be aware of just by looking. It doesn't mean 'know' in the sense of 'recognise'.

Comment: @katebunting I think you are right,  and intuitively it  makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You wouldn't know it to look at it" is a stock formula that means its (whatever it is) appearance makes you think that it is less in some regard than it really is. The formula does have an odd feel to it: "by looking at it" seems more natural to me.

Comment: I think there is a hidden emphatic "to see it" almost  accusatory. Where "by looking at it" seems  indifferent.